What does this text mean in the context of the approximating solution for method of weighted residuals?
I am going through some introductory material on spectral/hp element methods and the book has a section on method of weighted residuals. I am paraphrasing the contents of the book below.
If we consider a linear differential equation  $L(u) = 0$ subjected to appropriate initial/boundary conditions, it's approximate solution $u^{\delta}(x)$ can be written in the form $$u^{\delta}(x,t) = u_0(x,t) + \sum_{i=1}^{N_{DOF}}\hat{u_i}(t)\phi_i(x)$$, where $\phi_i(x)$ are trial/expansion functions, $\hat{u_i}(t)$ are the $N_{DOF}$ unknown coefficients, and $u_o(x,t)$ is selected to satisfy the initial/boundary conditions. Now the book says and I quote,

We note that, by definition, $\phi_i(x)$ satisfies homogenous boundary
conditions(i.e., zero on Dritchlet boundaries) since the known
function $u_0(x,t)$ already satisfies the boundary conditions of the
problem

I am unable to understand what this statement means. I understand what homogenous/non-homogenous BCs are but I don't understand what they mean in the quoted text. Can someone please explain?

If $u=f$ on the boundary, then take $u_0=f$ on the boundary and $\phi_i=0$ on the boundary and their sum will satisfy $u^\delta = f$ on the boundary.
